# nginx include fastcgi_params order

Tags: nginx

when i have something this:

```
location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

    expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
    include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  ID_DEVELOPER_MODE 1;
}
```

is it important where to put the include directive? because the file /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params already has a SCRIPT_FILENAME declaration inside.

Answer (score 4):

The `fastcgi_param` directive is [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_param). And although it is clear regarding inheritance it is not clear regarding the setting of the same parameter more than once (at the same level).

By experiment, it seems that `nginx` silently overwrites a previous value at the same level.

So the answer to your question is to place the `include` directive *before* any `fastcgi_param` directives that take priority.

Comment: The documentation itself contains many examples where it includes it after some `fastcgi_param`s -- See https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/ -- Is the documentation misleading somehow?

Comment: @jweyrich Indeed it is. If the parameter you are setting is guaranteed not to be in the file (such as in the link you cite), you can arrange the statements in either order . But the contents of `fastcgi_params` varies across different distributions, so if I am answering a question where I need to set a parameter, I sometimes emphasize that the order *may* be significant.